# SWF file seek information

Tags: actionscript-3, activex, flash, seek

Is it possible to get and set seek position of a swf file (either in ActionScript 2/3 or ActiveX API of Flash Player) ?

I tried to use frame number at first (to determine which part of the movie is being played) however sometimes whole animation has 2 frames and it does not help.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your loaded SWF contains all animation on the stage timeline ( i mean the top level ) then the progress you are seeking is:

```
var progress:Number = swf.currentFrame / swf.totalFrames;
```

if you want to set seek:

```
swf.gotoAndPlay ( progress * swf.totalFrames )
```

Also it can be that the all animation is not on the top level, but in the movieClip, which address you know, i mean stage.getChildByName ( 'something ).getChildeByName ('something )...

but if you have an swf where are multiple movieclips, and they are playing independantly, then nothing i can help....

Comment: is there any third option? i mean a flash animation with only 1 frame and no movie clip? maybe scripting or sth?

Comment: that also can be the case, when all animation is programicaly based, you would be able to track it.

Comment: I'm not sure about your real point here, but if those are yours swf's and you creating them you can look at this: http://www.greensock.com/timelinelite/

Comment: unfortunately those can be just any swf file, most likely not created by me. so if the all animation is programmed in 1 frame, then we cannot seek back and/or forth (ok maybe back), right? we will have to wait till the code executes and then we can see the results

Comment: and do you have any sample swf file that consists only of 1 frame and animation is completely done by scripting? i was looking for some samples on the internet however no outcome so far...

Answer (score 0):

Not without coding something in to the SWF as far as I know.  Because animations in Flash can be in embedded MovieClips, or entirely scripted in a single frame, there is no easy way to detect the total playing time or how far an animation has progressed.  Any get/seek functionality, or even a progress broadcast, would have to be scripted in the SWF and accessed through [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html).

Answer (score -2):

Please be more specific about your problem. If your swf file is only 2 frames, then what is it that you are trying to seek through? Does your swf load a video, for example, and this is what you are trying to seek through? (In which case you can get properties of a video object's playback position and state).

Without more information, it's hard to provide a clear answer.

Comment: My swf file can consist of only 1 frame or it may consist of 100 frames, I am supposed to find a solution that will fit both. the problem is, lets say i have a swf with 1 frame. i want to fast-forward the animation and display things as if it was being played for 2 hours. is that possible?

Comment: If your swf has only 1 frame but it contains animation, then by definition it contains sub-movieclips. You could use frame navigation (goToFrame) on the root timeline and then loop through the display list to discover all the available sub-movieclips, and then use goToFrame on those.